# Qt platform plugin fails to load for other computers

Tags: python, windows, qt, matplotlib, pyinstaller

I have created an .exe from a python app with pyinstaller in Windows. This app opens some matplotlib windows. At first, at the opening of the matplotlib windows, it throwed me the error "This application failed to start because it could not load the Qt platform plugin 'Windows'". I did some digging around and found out that I had to set an enviromental variable 'QT_PLUGIN_PATH' to the value 'C:\Users\*user*\Miniconda2\Library\plugins'. It worked right but on my PC only. When I open the .exe in other PCs and open the matplotlib windows, it shows me the same error. Is there a way to make it work for every computer?

Comment: Seems to be a [common problem](https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5/issues/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They say, if you can't untie the knot, cut it out. That's what I did because I could not figure out a way, so I completely removed the Qt backend and added a Tk one with this line:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to package QT DLLs with the installer. These DLL's must be shipped with your app because your app has dependency on them. It works on your PC because you have QT packages installed on your machine.

Please follow the link below to see the sample code in order to create package that resolves the DLL issue.

https://github.com/carlosperate/pyinstaller-test/blob/master/package/pyqt5_test.spec

Comment: I edited my .spec file like the one in the link you provided but still the same problem persists. If I copy the dlls to the app folder manually will it work? If yes, which dlls are needed? I copied 'qminimal.dll', 'qoffscreen.dll' and 'qwindows.dll' but still with no result.

Comment: can you try this : https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5/issues/2
 just download depends.exe for here http://www.dependencywalker.com/ and find all the dependencies of your exe and copy them in local folder it should work